# How to get a scope variable from a directive in a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am building a custom directive where i want to access the isolated scope variable from my controller.

Here is what the html looks like:

```
<display-user-comment userId="user.id"></display-user-comment>
```

Here is what my directive looks like:

```
    app.directive('displayUserComment', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'user_comment.html',
            scope: {
                userId: '='
            },
            controller: 'UserCommentController as userCmtCtrl'
        };
    })
```

Here is what my controller looks like:

```
app.controller('UserCommentController', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {

    //How to get access to userId ??
}]);
```

How to get access to the isolated to variable userId in my controller?

here is the plunker url
http://plnkr.co/edit/9Lh9sPp8o7gZLs1h8RDs?p=preview

Comment: `$scope.user.id`? You're passing a scope variable (`user.id`) to the directive. So it's already in the scope.

Comment: @JBNizet, not it is not, it is only in the isolated scope, and my controller get instanced before my directive(

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. What does the directive do? How can it show a user comment if you don't pass it the user ID? Please provide a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: i pass it thought the directive, but in my controller, i tried to get it like $scope.userId, $scope.user.id .... but still undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change userId to user-id in the html. angular "normalizes" the attribute name, so user-id as an attribute name in your html becomes scope.userId in your directive.

For more info https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive:

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
> Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

Answer (score 2):

You were using the wrong attribute name.  When you camelcase a directive attribute, it is rendered with dashes instead (userId = user-id).  Here is the updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/I8TWzTBh7IvZZxtaQ5sk?p=preview

```
 <display-user-comment user-id="23"></display-user-comment>
```